# Windows Java-based apps not working

Tags: windows, java

After updating the Java JRE to 7u25, many Java-based applications not works as usual, the I upgrade Java to 7u45, and still the apps not working.

Minecraft start screen not showing, have to press TAB key to select the Run button and press ENTER to run the game.

Netbeans IDE it's running, but none it's showing on the screen.

Eclipse and JDownloader are working fine.

I cannot run the Java Control Panel, it's only shows the Java icon at the taskbar.

My System 
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64Bits 
Java: 
java version "1.7.0_45" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18) 
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed my problem.

I do this:

- uninstall JRE7u45
- Delete te files at: C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun
- restarted my computer
- installed JDK7u45
- On the Java Control Panel set the Compatibility: Disable Visual Themes
- Run the Java Control Panel and clean the cache files, also lowered to 100MB

and everithing is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Manually clear you Java applet cache.

Normally you would open the control panel applet to find that path, but since you can't, you'll have to do a little hunting.

On Windows Vista+ it's usually in

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache
```

If that doesn't work, completely uninstall Java via Add/Remove programs, ensure the `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun` folder is deleted (if not, then delete it), and then reinstall Java.

Comment: none of that worked... i'll try uninstalling the JRE7u45 and install the JDK7u45